# How can i know what kind of exception a class will throw?

Tags: c#, exception

is there any page from MSDN or somewhere can tell us, what kind of exception will be throw from a specific class?

for example, FtpWebRequest. how can i find out what kind of exception it will throw??
the page from MSDN is not really helpful
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Thanks

Comment: In Visual Studio, Intelli-sense will give you that information.

Comment: How can a class throw an exception? A class is not an action.

Comment: Great question, especially when you notice that in Java you declare the exceptions ahead of time. The time honored tradition of hacking into the code using Reflector and figuring it out from there is not a real solution worthy of a modern language, it is just a patch. I am not a hater (I've been developing in .NET since VS2002). I think it is a very construtive topic of conversation to be had within the C# community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes don't throw exceptions. Members (Properties and Methods) do. So you need to look at the documentation for the individual members to know.

Comment: For example, take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As others said, the intellisense will tell you. In addition, you could [step into the framework code itself](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx).

In addition, the documentation for each method contains the list of exceptions it might throw.  [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx).